# Set cookies for ajax request, when "JsonResponse" is returned

Tags: python, django, django-3.1

When I use normal (not ajax) request, I do:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.http import JsonResponse

response = redirect('/some_page')
response.set_cookie(key='key1', value='value1', max_age=3600) 
response.set_cookie(key='key2', value='value2', max_age=3600) 
return response
```

and it works and cookies are set.

Though, when I use ajax request, my view returns something like:

`return JsonResponse({'res': 'success'})`

and I'm not figured out, how I can set cookies, when `JsonResponse` is returned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **`redirect('/some_page')`** is returning a [**`HttpResponse`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse) and [**`JsonResponse`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects) is a subclass of `HttpResponse`.

So, you can use the same [**`set_cookie(...)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse.set_cookie) method here too

```
def sample_view(request):
    response = JsonResponse({"foo": "bar"})
    response.set_cookie(key='key1', value='value1', max_age=3600)
    return response
```